# Googlecode: View html file directly from svn source

Tags: svn, google-code

Is it possible to view a file as real HTML instead of raw text in googlecode svn?

Ex: http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/test/index.html

As opposed to http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Somehow all the source code including CSS and scripts are not processed and wrapped in a big *pre* tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Extracted from : http://manjeetdahiya.com/2010/09/29/serving-html-documentation-from-google-code-svn/

Basically you have to set the mime-type of the file using your svn client